# How to share a module between a parent and child module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-module

I'm new to Angular. I want to use a component (FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent) with routing and with a dialog. However I can't import a component in different modules.

I've created a shared.module to import the FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent, to be used in others modules. These two modules are AppLogged.module and Funcionarios.module. AppLogged.module is a parent of the Funcionarios.module.

Shared.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent } from '../features/funcionarios/funcionarios-altera-senha/funcionarios-altera-senha.component';


@NgModule({
  entryComponents:[
    FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent],

  declarations: [
    FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[
    FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

AppLogged.module

```
@NgModule({

  entryComponents: [AppLogedComponent, PesquisaColaboradorComponent, EfetuarPagamentoComponent,
  PesquisaClienteComponent, PesquisaPedidoComponent, CotacaoVendaComponent, CadastroVeiculoComponent,
  PesquisaVeiculoComponent, CompraComponent, CadastroClienteComponent, SolicitarTransferenciaComponent,
  SaidaTransferenciaComponent, ConfirmarRecebimentoComponent, PesquisaEstoqueComponent,TextoLivreComponent,
  DetalheRecebimentoComponent, PesquisaPedCompraTransfComponent,  EfetuarPagamentosComponent],

  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    AppLogedRoutingModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    NgxCurrencyModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
  ],


  declarations: [AppLogedComponent, MenuSideComponent, HeaderComponent, PesquisaColaboradorComponent,
  EfetuarPagamentoComponent, PesquisaClienteComponent, PesquisaPedidoComponent, CotacaoVendaComponent,
  CadastroVeiculoComponent, PesquisaVeiculoComponent,CompraComponent,CadastroClienteComponent,
  SolicitarTransferenciaComponent, SaidaTransferenciaComponent, ConfirmarRecebimentoComponent,
  PesquisaEstoqueComponent,TextoLivreComponent, DetalheRecebimentoComponent, PesquisaPedCompraTransfComponent,  EfetuarPagamentosComponent],

  exports: [AppLogedComponent],
})

export class AppLogedModule { }
```

```
Funcionarios.module

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [FuncionariosComponent, ],
  declarations: [FuncionariosComponent, ],
  bootstrap: [FuncionariosComponent, ],
  exports: [ FuncionariosComponent,  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxMaskModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatCardModule,
    FuncionariosRoutingModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    SharedModule ],
})
export class FuncionariosModule { }
```

Comment: Did you try importing `SharedModule` in `AppLogged.module` similar to `Funcionarios.module`? You must import `SharedModule` in all modules those want to use `FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent`.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Although I'm getting an error when importing shared.module within Funcionarios.module

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
</div>
```
If I remove the importing the error doesn't occur

Comment: I added FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule, Within imports and exports of Shared.module and resolved the issue (Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. (" </div> )

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SharedModule` to the `imports` array of both the `FuncionariosModule` and the `AppLogedModule` in order to have access to the `FuncionariosAlteraSenhaComponent`. As of now, you're only adding it to the `imports` array of the `FuncionariosModule`.

Also, your Angular Modules are very tightly coupled with the Angular Material Modules. Ideally you should create a separate module for that. Something like an `AppMaterialModule`, that would add all the Angular Material modules that you are using to the `imports` and the `exports` array.

You will then be able to have access to these Material Modules by simply adding the `AppMaterialModule` module to the `imports` array of your Module. It will help make your code more manageable.

> **PS:** Also, are you sure you want to add all those components to the `entryComponents` array in your `AppLogedModule`?